# Can I Nest Templates in Meteor JS?

Tags: templates, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm a bit new to meteor, but it seems pretty amazing.

**I'd like to be able to nest templates and pass parameters to templates like this**:

```
<template name="parent">
    <h1>Parent Header</h1>
    {{> child state="parent" }}
</template>
```

I noticed that the accounts-ui package does this sort of thing, but I just get errors. They do this: `{{loginButtons align="right"}}`, which seems to come from a handler? 
(source: http://docs.meteor.com/#accountsui)

**Is this a possible way to do nesting? Would I need to use some nifty handlers instead?**

Comment: the loginButton is a helper function rather than a template name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current implementation of the templating engine you are not able pass params to templates. But in the future you will.
Though, you can do simple nesting.

Comment: Do you have any reference to a press release or anything where they say it'll be available one day?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch_videos?title=Popular+uploads&feature=c4-overview&type=0&video_ids=MUW8kxpze0Y%2ClSAKFkxq4jA%2C2oEPJGNNpkM%2CRSASfz_vU2k%2CAc9ou9Vi0q8%2CvRijKvXPHXM%2C2ntHe1UW1QI%2CN08GXqmSWuk%2CeXV29mYb-a4%2CBLLOWxKQY8k%2CNdBPY98o6eM&more_url=